# Javascript SetInterval with warning

Tags: javascript

I want a certain function to run every 10 minutes, but I want to warn the user of this event 10 seconds up front.

So i made this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){

    alert('Warning! Refresh in 10 seconds');

    window.setInterval(function(){

        applyfilter();
    }, 590000);

}, 600000);
```

However, this does not work. The timers don't stay "in sync". How to fix this?

Comment: Draw the timeline on the paper and mark both events on the scale. It's a basic problem, really. See the delay to the first event, see the delay before the next event, and so on.

Comment: man :) your code waits 10 minutes then show warning, and wait another 10 (-10 seconds) minutes to appy filter

Comment: The reason is, that javascript is single threading. If you need a nearly exact timer you have to deal with real time values. If you start the interval, e. g. every 0.5 second, calculate the end time and trigger the warning 10 seconds before end time.

Comment: To clarify, the inner function doesn't begin until the outer one completes. You won't see an alert until 19:50 has passed.

Comment: So, I should make the outer function 590 seconds, and the inner one 10 seconds? After that, it start counting from 0 again?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can count how much time passes in a interval for 10 seconds, and decide when filter is applied or message is shown. like,

```
var time_start = Date.now();
var warning_done = false;
var applied_filter = false;
window.setInterval(function(){
    if (warning_done === false && Date.now() - time_start > 10*60*1000 - 10*1000){
       alert('Warning! Refresh in 10 seconds');
       warning_done = true;
    } else if (applied_filter === false && Date.now() - time_start > 10*60*1000 ){
        applyfilter();
        applied_filter = true;
    }
}, 10*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more complicated than nested setIntervals will do cleanly. How about this?

```
var startTimer = function(){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    applyfilter();
    startTimer();
  }, 600000);
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    alert('Warning! Refresh in 10 seconds');
  }, 590000);
};
startTimer(); //on doc load, etc
```

Comment: and obviously you could chain the two inner setTimeouts, but I thought seeing them both start at 0 each time would help outline what actually needs to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Because JavaScript is single-threaded, the timers will get out of sync as soon as the alert box pops up.

Best to display the warning within an element.  You can then use `setTimeout()`, so you have only one timer running at a time.

I've changed the delays to 6s and 3s for demonstration purposes here:

```js
var output= document.getElementById('output');

function applyfilter() {
  output.textContent= 'Filter applied!';
  warning();
}

function warning() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    output.textContent= 'Warning!  Refresh in 3 seconds';
    setTimeout(function() {
      applyfilter();  
    }, 3000);
  }, 6000);
}
  
warning();
```

```css
#output {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```